# Install LaTeX on Mac OS Lion 10.7.5

Tags: installing, mactex

I need to install LaTeX on a old MacBook holding a Mac OS Lion 10.7.5 .
Apparently the new version of MacTeX distribution require Mac OS 10.10 or higher, and I am not managing to find old versions of the distribution.
Some ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You can simply install texlive directly (https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html). It support osx 10.6-10.9 with the `x86_64-darwinlegacy` binary.

This will give you a complete and up to date tex distribution.

> At this point you can stop reading this answer, as you have everything you need to build tex documents.

In comparision to mactex this solution only lacks some additional programs, for example a GUI to update your tex distribution (TeX Live Utility).

If you nevertheless want these program, you have two possibilities:

- you could install an older version of mactex ([see DG's answer for details](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/398750/36296)). This will install old versions of these additional programs which work well alongside an up to date vanilla texlive installation
- manually install current versions of the additional programs you desire. Suitable versions can be acquired from their websites (http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/texshop.html, http://bibdesk.sourceforge.net/, http://amaxwell.github.io/tlutility/, http://excalibur.sourceforge.net/downloads.html,https://www.chachatelier.fr/latexit/latexit-downloads.php?lang=en)

Comment: it is indeed possible to use TeXDist control panel (which is slightly buggy under mac os x 10.9.5, each use has to be followed by quitting System Preferences before new use) to switch TeX distribution years, but it is no easy task for general user to update the needed structure for TL2017 for example.

Comment: @jfbu I never used the TeXDist control panel, but most of mactex's gui applications let you simply adjust the path to the new vanilla texlive in their preferences, e.g. in the tex live utilities this works without problem.

Comment: agreed (the TeXDist functionality into TexLive Utility I think with MacTeX 2016 already), but here we are talking about systems for which no MacTeX install is possible. Very very old systems, completely antiquated like 10.9.5 which was brand new in 2012.

Comment: @jfbu Now you lost me. Old systems is all this threat is about.

Comment: sorry I probably got unclear. But you referred to MacTeX GUI apps and MacTeX provides no support for pre 10.10 systems. However you can surely install separately apps usually bundled with MacTeX such as TeXLive Utility or TeXShop. I mentioned TeXDist as I got it from some earlier MacTeX, and I am still using it. But the recommended way is TLU which now incorporates its support. However on Mavericks you will have to install TLU directly.

Answer (score 2):

There seem to be two possibilities:

1. Install an old version of MacTeX from the archive on this ftp server:  ftp://ftp.tug.org/historic/systems/mactex
2. Install TexLive 2017 with the unix installer (which egreg managed to do). Instructions are in the answers to this question: [New tex live or old MacTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/377576/new-tex-live-or-old-mactex)

*(I'd go with [samcarter's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/398752/29873), which is more elegant and straightforward)*

Comment: But aren't there also a (hidden) build of the latest TL but for older Mac OS X? Build by others. The versions here are just older MacTeX versions.

Comment: @daleif : that is what samcarter is referring to.

Comment: @HerbSchulz that's the one. Strange it is not mentioned explicitly on the mactex page

Comment: @daleif : not at all. Those versions of TeX Live 2017 are not associated with MacTeX and developed independently.

Comment: @HerbSchulz but, the mactex team chose (with good reason) not to support older versions, they could mention that the other solution exist.