# Install Latex on OS X Mavericks 10.9.5

Tags: mac, mactex

I downgraded my MacBook to OS X Mavericks and wanted to reinstall the MacTex package. The latest update of the package requires OS X Yosemite or newer versions. Does anyone of you know how can I get it. I was used to typeset with TexShop.

Thank you.

Comment: You can install texlive https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html, it supports 10.9. Texshop provides suitable versions http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/texshop/obtaining.html

Comment: see related question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/398742/install-latex-on-mac-os-lion-10-7-5

Comment: if you relied on the TeXDist control panel and still want to use it to change distributions (your PATH contains `/Library/TeX/texbin`) you will have to update the data in `/Library/TeX` which is only easy if you master symlinks and for example know how use edit mode in an Emacs dired buffer to copy them and adjust in mass. If this sounds scary and do not need to switch back to TL2016, TL2015, etc.., then after installing via the texlive procedure, make sure your PATH is updated to contain `/usr/local/texlive/2017/bin/x86_64-darwinlegacy` (assuming standard location).

Comment: You will then have to install TeXShop independently. Side note: the binaries distributed with TeXLive 2017 for 10.9.5 suffer from a big speed problem. I had to replace them with the MacPorts ones. Sorry if this all sounds a bit depressing...

Comment: @jfbu which speed issues do you experience for 10.9?

Comment: @samcarter at least 40% slower than with TeXLive 2016. See http://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2017-September/040571.html and other messages in the thread. I have solved the problem by temporarily minimally installing the MacPorts TeX, and copying over the binaries to the TeXLive location. (I then probably re-compiled the formats; I kept the darwinlegacy repertory as emergency fall-back but I have not need it so far. I had to copy from it in particular the kpsewhich family of binaries to my new bin directory as they have some hard-coded paths in them; details are a bit fuzzy now in memory)

Comment: @jfbu Interesting! I just compared compiling times and pdflatex from TL2017 is for me actually 5% faster compared to frozen state of TL2016.

Comment: @samcarter good! but I deduce you are on 10.10 or later `;-)`

Comment: @jfbu I am on 10.9.5, that's why I was curious which problems you encountered with that.

Comment: @samcarter I don't know what to say then. It _might_ be that TeXLive udpated the binaries. Very intriguing situation. I don't think being on an mac book air changes something actually I think I did the timing tests also on an iMac under 10.9.5. back then in september.

Comment: @jfbu macs are just capricious - no two behave the same :)

Comment: @samcarter in my `x86_64-darwinlegacy` the pdftex binary is dated April 26, 2017 and occupies `2962616` bytes. What about yours?

Comment: @jfbu the very same for me. Strange. As test I compiled `\Blinddocument`

Comment: @samcarter interesting. Maybe compilation time is too short. Have you tried the test http://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2017-September/040571.html ? (sorry for big interludes in-between my comments)

Comment: @jfbu Please excuse the late reply, I misplaced the link to this question. I tested with the short tex code from the mailing list you linked to and for this example TL16 is indeed faster than TL17. The discrepancy is not as big for me, but TL17 is about 5% slower. (I made 10 test for each year and compared the mean values)

Comment: @samcarter thanks for the info! I am a no-ob in C compiler settings hence I have no idea what's going on, I imagine there is either something missing or something extra on my Macs in comparison with yours (that's quite an impressive deduction `;-)` )... (at)Mojca would know!