# Unable to download LaTex on Mac OX-10.7.5

Tags: mac

I have tried to follow the advice given here, but am not able to do anything with the files that are contained in the downloaded folder:

[Install LaTeX on Mac OS Lion 10.7.5](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/398742/install-latex-on-mac-os-lion-10-7-5#new-answer?newreg=a5eb948a0cc8419eabf72ffc0a9c41eb)

There is only one file that seems readable, but it is for UNIX--and I just get lost after opening that one from the downloaded folder.  I am not at all good at this; so, apologies in advance.

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the Terminal for this. Don't worry, it's not difficult.

I'm doing the exact steps listed below on a Mac with OS X 10.5, but they're the same with OS X 10.7.

1. Open the Terminal
2. Type in `cd` followed by the <kbd>Return</kbd> key
3. Type in `mkdir texlive && cd texlive`<kbd>Return</kbd>
4. Go to Safari and to http://tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html
5. Click on the link `install-tl-unx.tar.gz`
6. When the download is complete, go back to the Terminal
7. Type in `mv ~/Downloads/install-tl-unx.tar.gz .`<kbd>Return</kbd> (don't forget the trailing period)
8. Type in `tar zxf install-tl-unx.tar.gz`<kbd>Return</kbd>
9. Type in `ls`<kbd>Return</kbd>
10. This should show something like

    ```
    install-tl-20171211   install-tl-unx.tar.gz
    ```

    The date in the first name could be different
11. Type in `cd install-tl-20171211`<kbd>Return</kbd> (using the precise name you got in the previous step)
12. Type in `sudo perl install-tl`<kbd>Return</kbd>
13. You will be asked for your password, type it in and hit <kbd>Return</kbd>
14. You should see many lines appearing, ending with

    ```
    Actions:
     <I> start installation to hard disk
     <P> save installation profile to 'texlive.profile' and exit
     <H> help
     <Q> quit

    Enter command:
    ```

    with a black rectangle on the last line
15. Type in `I`<kbd>Return</kbd>
16. Wait until the installation is complete
17. Type in `export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2017/bin/i386-darwin:$PATH`<kbd>Return</kbd>
18. Type in `tex --version`<kbd>Return</kbd> You should get

    ```
    TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2017)
    kpathsea version 6.2.3
    Copyright 2017 D.E. Knuth.
    There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
    covered by the terms of both the TeX copyright and
    the Lesser GNU General Public License.
    For more information about these matters, see the file
    named COPYING and the TeX source.
    Primary author of TeX: D.E. Knuth.
    ```

Now setup TeXShop or TeXworks to look in the directory `/usr/local/texlive/2017/bin/i386-darwin` and you should be OK.

Comment: Please do you know the procedure for Macbook pro ?. I failled to apply the above scheem with mac pro

Comment: @GuyFsone It depends on the version of Mac OS X, not on the Mac model.